# Backbone.js triggering route on navigate with pushState=true?

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I am using Backbone 0.92 and am experiencing different router behaviour in FF compared to Chrome.

In Firefox, navigating to this url does not trigger the "defaultRoute":

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

myRouter.navigate("?chapter=1")

//Router
routes: {
    '*path':        'defaultRoute',
}
```

Whereas in Chrome, navigate does trigger a refresh of the whole page.
What could be the cause?

Comment: `myRouter.navigate("?chapter=1",{trigger:true});` should work. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

PhD is correct that changing it to `myRouter.navigate("?chapter=1", {trigger: true});` resolve your issue.

However, it worth while noting that this is actually a chrome issue rather than a firefox issue.  Chrome for some reason seems to preload the router url which means the router method gets executed without you specifying that you want it to.

Either way, adding `{trigger: true}` is the expected way of executing navigations and will resolve your issue.